# SQL Join Two Tables Remove Duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

Okay I've been searching through all previously asked questions and I'm still having trouble.

I have two tables

Table MOVIES

```
mov_id
mov_name
actor_id
```

Table ACTOR

```
actor_id_2
actor_name
```

I want to join both tables into one table where it lists

1. mov_id
2. mov_name
3. actor_name

I'm trying to use JOIN WHERE actor_id = actor_id_2 except my code includes the duplicates of repeating the same actor_name 3 times.

[image: Example]

I've tried multiple ways of doing this, each way unsuccessful. I'm not sure which way would be the proper way to do this.

Comment: I dont understand, the example doesnt show duplicates- M_Name is different for each row and is unique to M_ID. One actor can play in multiple movies..

Comment: Yes. According to Wikipedia Idris Elba acted in all three movies from 2017 (and also The Dark Tower). If one row per actor is what you want, you can GROUP the result by actor_name and concatenate both movie_id and movie_name somehow. How exactly depends on the database type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Inner join which will join tables such that it selects records that have matching values in both tables, write your query as

```
select distinct t1.mov_id, t1.mov_name, t2.actor_name from MOVIES t1 inner join ACTOR t2 on t1.actor_id=t2.actor_id_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to build up your concept.

What you are applying is relational database using primary and foreign keys.

Whenever you have such scenario as above that you need to retrieve data from more than one table and they are related then `joins` are used.

Joins have many kinds, you can get their details and guidance in this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Now comes to your tables and data.

```
Select M.mov_id, M.mov_name, M.actor_name from Movies M
inner join Actor A on M.actor_id = A.actor_id_2
```

notice: after `on` keyword you can place multiple conditions for the join to get the most specific data as per your requirement.